# Multiple transaction

Tags: paypal

How can I do multiple transaction in Paypal.

I tried using following JSON request

```
{
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "credit_card",
    "funding_instruments": [
      {
        "credit_card": {
          "number": "5500005555555559",
          "type": "mastercard",
          "expire_month": 12,
          "expire_year": 2018,
          "cvv2": 111,
          "first_name": "Joe",
          "last_name": "Shopper"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "7.47",
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "description": "This is the payment transaction description."
    },{
      "amount": {
        "total": "9.71",
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "description": "This is the payment transaction description 2."
    }
  ]
}
```

But it gives the following response

{
  "name": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
  "details": [
    {
      "field": "transactions",
      "issue": "Only single payment transaction currently supported"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Invalid request - see details",
  "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR",
  "debug_id": "b18a0e6fdfe1d"
}